# How to show that $f(x)$ is never negative

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> $f(x)=x^4-2x^3-2x^2+a$
>   When $a=8$, show that $f(x)$ is never negative. $x^2-4x+4$ is a factor of $f(x)$.

How do I work out this question? I have tried using the factor theorem but I honestly have no idea on how to approach this question. Please give me a simple step by step method.

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with derivatives? One way would be to look for the critical points and notice what is the minimum value in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that $x^2 -4x + 4$ is never negative by factoring it. Then divide your polynomial by $x^2 - 4x + 4$ and show that the quotient polynomial is also never negative. Then you have that the product of two non-negative quantities is non-negative and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

Hint1: factor $x^2 - 4x  + 4$.  Hint 2: what is $f(x)/(x^2 - 4 x + 4)$?

Comment: f(x)/(x^2-4x+4) = x^2+2x+2